# Extract the last modification date from a DBpedia page

Tags: dbpedia

I wanna know how to extract the last modification date of a DBpedia page (for example: http://dbpedia.org/page/Cristiano_Ronaldo)?

Answer (score 0):

This information is not available through the current static DBpedia a/k/a DBpedia Snapshot (dataset as of 2016-10).

This information *is* available through the dynamic DBpedia Live.  For example, see <http://live.dbpedia.org/page/Cristiano_Ronaldo> which includes

```
dbo:wikiPageExtracted      2019-10-22 21:26:45Z (xsd:date)
dbo:wikiPageModified       2019-10-22 21:25:51Z (xsd:date)
```